# Запутался с множествами, нужна помощь

Tags: java, множества

Есть следующая задача:

Вводится несколько строк по два слова в каждой - имена двух друзей. Дружба - вещь взаимная(с двух сторон!!!). Иначе люди - не друзья.

Необходимо вывести ответ в соответствии с примерами ниже - список друзей. Список состоит из имен людей, список выстроен в лексографическом порядке(по алфавиту) по возрастанию, после имени человека идет фраза " дружит с : ", далее следует список имен его друзей, выстроенный так же по возрастанию.

```
Пример_1
Ввод:
Mike Nike
Oleg Petr
Mike Petr
Ivan Oleg

Вывод:
Ivan дружит с : Oleg 
Mike дружит с : Nike Petr 
Nike дружит с : Mike 
Oleg дружит с : Ivan Petr 
Petr дружит с : Mike Oleg 

Пример_2:
Ввод:
Петр Иван
Иван Петр
Олег Иван
Петр Олег

Вывод:
Иван дружит с : Олег Петр 
Олег дружит с : Иван Петр 
Петр дружит с : Иван Олег
```

Код у меня такой вот:

```
public class TestClass {
    private static Map<String, List<String>> friends = new TreeMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] pairs;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String s = in.nextLine();
            list.add(s);
        }
        for (String pair : list) {
            addFriends(pair);
        }
        printAllFriends();
    }
    public static void addFriends(String pair) {
        String first = pair.split(" ")[0];
        String second = pair.split(" ")[1];
        put(first, second);
        put(second, first);
    }
    private static void put(String one, String two) {
        if (!friends.containsKey(one)) {
            friends.put(one, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        friends.get(one).add(two);
    }

    public static void printAllFriends() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> pair : friends.entrySet()) {
            pair.getValue().sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
            System.out.println( pair.getKey() + " дружит с : " + String.join(" ",pair.getValue()));;
        }
    }
}
```

Все нормально с первым тестом - проходит, но на втором валится...такое чувство что не в алфавитном порядке сортирует и выводит, хотя вроде бы правильно все написал.
Дайте добрый совет, что поправить чтоб работало?

Comment: Как у вас первый тест проходит, если сканер всегда ожидает новую линию? Можете показать результаты тестов?

Comment: Тест проходит весьма тривиально) ctrl+d) именно таким образом ввод и прерывается.

Comment: "Олег дружил с Нике и Майком..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто замените `List` на `TreeSet` в мапе `friends`.

```java
private static Map<String, TreeSet<String>> friends = new TreeMap<>();
```

Два последних метода тогда записываются так:

```java
private static void put(String one, String two) {
    if (!friends.containsKey(one)) {
        friends.put(one, new TreeSet<>());
    }
    friends.get(one).add(two);
}

public static void printAllFriends() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, TreeSet<String>> pair : friends.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println( pair.getKey() + " дружит с : " + String.join(" ",pair.getValue()));;
    }
}
```

Вывод был неправильный из-за того, что имена дублировались.
Теперь же не нужно ни сортировать список имён, ни убирать дубликаты, это за вас сделает `TreeSet`.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас попробую потетсить.

Comment: @СанСаныч А, нет. Не увидел, у вас `TreeMap`, не надо сортировать.

Comment: Я уж думал что с ума схожу...все тесты проваливает, хотя вывод тот что надо. Оказывается, что нужно было пробелы в конце каждой строки добавить)))

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Все работает!

Comment: @СанСаныч все тесты проваливает, хотя вывод тот, что надо? Это как? Зачем пробелы в конце каждой строки? И так всё отлично работает, только что протестировал.

Comment: Да, все отлично работает. Пробелы в конце строк на выводе - это одно из условий задания. На которое я не обратил внимания и не придал этому условию значения в силу его незначительности(я его даже здесь в условиях задачи не описал). А в этом был определенный подвох. Так сказать - тест на внимательность.

Comment: @СанСаныч какая разница, есть там пробелы или нет? Ваш код всё равно сохраняет только первые два элемента от `pair.split(" ")`. Кстати, `split()` - затратный метод, лучше сохранить его результат в массив, и потом уже этот массив использовать, чем вызывать метод каждый раз.